# React pagination without backend

Tags: reactjs

I have the following Parent Component that contains several Child components:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <Child id='1'/>
      <Child id='2'/>
      <Child id='3'/>
      <Child id='4'/>
      <Child id='5'/>
      <Child id='6'/>
      <Child id='7'/>
      <Child id='8'/>
    </div>
    }
}
```

I want to have pagination in the Parent class that shows maximum 3 Child components per 'page'. Is there a way to do that without a complex backend integration?

Comment: Yes, pagination can be done entirely clientside

Comment: What's the best option for my case?

Comment: If you read the items from a list you can use [this code](https://github.com/alexjolig/Professional-pagination-using-react-without-JSX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a small demo which shows how you can accomplish something like that.](https://codesandbox.io/s/3x8j0n64yp) It works by keeping a single variable in state for the current page being viewed, and rendering elements conditionally depending on whichever is the current page. You can add onto this with individual links that set the page directly, or whatever you prefer.

For anything more complex, look into routing, which is the concept of syncing your app state to the URL bar, to enable the user to use back/forward buttons in the browser for navigation. [React Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy) is one of many libraries that can be used to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

use a state variable like current_page_no which you can update from buttons like prev, next. Then just display 3 children starting at current_page_no*3.

Comment: Could you please explain the "just display 3 children" a bit more detailed? How?

Comment: well it's difficult without knowing how you store the children. Let's say they are contained in an array passed in by a prop call my_children.

Comment: ...continued ... You could loop starting from start to end index and put this new array inside your rendered div. Kingdaro's looks like he has created a full example.